# List.containsSlice

Tags: functional-programming, scala, reinventing-the-wheel, backtracking

In an effort to strengthen my functional programming, I'm reading Functional Programming in Scala. One of the assignments is to implement a function that does the same operation as `containsSlice` in the List API.

```
@tailrec
  def hasSublist[T](list: List[T], currSub: List[T], origList: List[T], origSub: List[T]): Boolean = {
    (list, currSub) match {
      case (_, Nil) => true
      case (Nil, _) => false
      case (h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2) if h1 == h2 => hasSublist(t1, t2, origList, origSub)
      case (h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2) => hasSublist(origList.tail, origSub, origList.tail, origSub)
    }
  }

def hasSublist[T](list: List[T], sublist: List[T]): Boolean = hasSublist(list, sublist, list, sublist)
```

The second `hasSublist` is the function one would call. The first is the helper function.

I generally like my implementation. However, I wonder if there is a cleaner way of doing backtracking after partially matching the sublist and then finding that it doesn't completely match. Currently, I keep track of the list I am checking against in a variable passed to the function on every call, and likewise with the sublist that is being searched for. It seems a bit hacky to me although I can certainly live with it if there isn't a simple way to do it better. Any insight from experienced FP and Scala people would be fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion usually makes backtracking easy.  If it doesn't, your recursive function is probably doing too much.  Yours does.  The reason you built it that way is because your helper function returns a binary (boolean) value but you actually have 3 possible states at any one time

1. Did match this segment of the list
2. Did not match this segment of the list
3. Ran out of list.

You deal with this by carrying *all* of your state forwards, making your code more complex and hard to read than it needs.

All you need is a nice functional way to return 3 states and your code can become much simpler.  You must have been introduced to the **Option** monad by now.  All you need to do is have your helper function (which should be hidden *inside* your hasSublist function, by the way) return **Option[Boolean]**.  Now you can return 3 states:

1. **true** (Found a match)
2. **false** (Did not find a match)
3. **Nothing** (Ran out of list)

Here is one way to do this:

```
def hasSublist[T](list: List[T], sub: List[T]): Boolean = {
  def matchSub(ls: List[T], ss: List[T]): Option[Boolean] = (ls, ss) match {
    case (_, Nil) => Some(true)
    case (Nil, _) => None
    case (x :: xs, y :: ys) if x == y => matchSub(xs, ys)
    case (_, _) => Some(false)
  }

  matchSub(list, sub) match {
    case None => false
    case Some(false) => hasSublist(list.tail, sub)
    case _ => true
 }
}
```

It should be clear that this is simpler.  It separates the business of matching the sublist to the *current* list from deciding whether to return a definite result or recur over the tail of the list. In the latter case, we recur using the *outer* function, not the inner, making it easier to backtrack and maintain appropriate state (recursion does this for us, simply).

I only used pattern matching and recursion in the second half of the function to make it simple and obvious.  I would prefer to fold over the list and to apply **fold** or **map** to the Option[Boolean] result, but I don't know if you have covered those subtleties yet.  **However**, because I have separated concerns in a functional manner, it is very easy to change either or both halves of my code to use fold/map.  The outer function can be redesigned simply with no change to the inner function, or vice versa.

**EDIT: adding map and fold examples as requested**

Using **map** and **getOrElse** to replace the outer half:

```
  matchSub(list, sub) map {found => 
    if (found) true else hasSublist(list.tail, sub)
  } getOrElse false
```

If an **Option** contains a value, **map** unpacks it, applies the function and wraps the result in **Some**.  If it contains **None**, it simply returns **None**.  I don't think I need to explain **getOrElse** ;)

Using **fold**

```
  matchSub(list, sub).fold(false) {found =>
    if (found) true else hasSublist(list.tail, sub)
  }
```

**Option**'s **fold** evaluates and returns the first parameter only if the Option contains **Nothing**.  Otherwise it unwraps the value and applies the function.

There is much disagreement about which is better.

- **fold** is not obvious to the non-expert and doesn't behave quite like other folds.  But it is typesafe.
- **map + getOrElse** is more obvious than **fold** (not as obvious as pattern matching) but can cause surprising errors because **getOrElse** will happily return any type that is a subtype of what is expected by whatever is calling map/getOrElse.  Nothing compels it to be of the same type as whatever is wrapped in Option.
- **scalaz** fans prefer to use their **opt** type and have access to more consistent functions
- Martin Odersky prefers pattern matching.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for when I posted my question. You nailed it. I had considered using a separate mechanism like your match statement, but without Option, it would've been fairly ugly. I am wondering if you could add an implementation using fold. I tried, but haven't had success.

Comment: Do you want me to add examples of how fold and map would work or are you still working it out for yourself?

Comment: I am very much stuck. It would really help if you could show me.

Comment: That's done.  Hope it makes sense.

Comment: OH! That's what you meant. I was trying to implement matchSub in terms of foldLeft. Thanks for the explanations. Fantastic answer.

Comment: Using foldLeft on the list is inefficient.  foldLeft will go all the way to the end of the list, when you actually want to short circuit as soon as you have found a match.  Sometimes simple recursion really is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a helper function that you do not intend for others to call, hide it as a nested function.

The fourth case is a catch-all, which could be simplified to `(_, _)`.

```
def hasSublist[T](list: List[T], sublist: List[T]): Boolean = {
  @tailrec
  def sublistHelper[T](currList: List[T], currSub: List[T], origList: List[T], origSub: List[T]): Boolean = {
    (currList, currSub) match {
      case (_, Nil) => true
      case (Nil, _) => false
      case (h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2) if h1 == h2 => sublistHelper(t1, t2, origList, origSub)
      case (_, _) => sublistHelper(origList.tail, origSub, origList.tail, origSub)
    }
  }

  sublistHelper(list, sublist, list, sublist)
}
```

---

Here's a simpler implementation that uses `List.tails` and `List.startsWith`.  I don't know if you consider that cheating in your quest to reinvent the wheel.

```
def hasSublist[T](list: List[T], sublist: List[T]): Boolean = {
  list.tails.find(candidate => candidate.startsWith(sublist)).nonEmpty
}
```

Comment: I think it is probably cheating ;)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I was looking for more of a conceptual improvement to my approach, which @itsbruce provided. The second snippet is cheating for me, but the author of the book did the same thing, so...